# How to using nav drawer Sliding menu with fragment for main activity in android?

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I want to Sliding menu Just using through Swipe. I am using 
this below link,
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

But it is use Activity class for main class and I want to Fragment for main class for Sliding.
How it is Possible?

Comment: The most common pattern ; An activity is a container for all your fragments. So, your activity will have the navigation drawer and depending on the user selection in the navigation drawer you can change the fragment inside the activity.

Answer (score -1):

I think, you must using support design library and [NavigationDrawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)
like this. according to this article:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <!-- The main content view -->
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  <!-- The navigation drawer -->
  <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and also you can find some tutorial in [this](http://www.recursiverobot.com/post/59642335041/trying-slidingpanelayout-with-fragments-in) blog and many more resources.